SQLITE3: printing result gives none but doing same for result[0] gives the result
Hello i am trying to create a flask app. i am facing problem where datatype of result is none but result[0] is a string.
Code:
def fetch_file(self,token):
    with self.connect() as db:
        try:
            cursor = db.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT Exten FROM FILE_SHARE WHERE TOKEN = ?;",(token,))
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            
            return result
        except s.Error as e:
            return chalk.red(f"Error fetching file extention for token: {token}")

Flask app:
@app.route("/<token>")
def disp(token):
    exten = dbmgr.fetch_file(token)
    print(exten[0])
    flnm = f"./uploads/{token+'.'+exten[0]}"
    if os.path.isfile(flnm):
        return send_file(flnm)
    else:
        return "nope"

what should have happened: if i visit example.com/MZ it should have fetched the extension of file(which is png in this case) and then display the file in the browser.
what's happening: Everything works fine but it still gives this error:
print(exten[0])
          ^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable 

print(exten[0]) prints png in my console but still gives the above error.

When you run it in console you get a result, but when you run it via the web server you get None? Make sure you're connecting to the same database in both cases.

From the error, what was returned is None, that means the token does not exist

This issue come from your query return None. Need if !exten: return "nopde for checking none value

no what i am trying to say is when i print variable result it gives None in my console but when i print result[0] it gives the value but also the error i mentioned above.

It can't print the value and also the error. You must be seeing a previous value.
